# How to apply theme source code to Shiny widgets?

Tags: css, shiny, bootswatch

Sorry, I have googled forever and I don't find the answer:

I have downloaded a css-file from [Bootswatch](https://bootswatch.com/pulse/) and I have put it in my `www` directory where I have my `app.R`. Now I want to style my widgets to look like the different options presented at Bootswatch.

For example, to style an `actionButton` in the secondary button style, I put:

```
actionButton(
    inputId = "action",
    class = "btn-success")
```

How do I apply the more complicated styling source code? For example, for the `selectInput` widget the source code at Bootswatch is:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1" style="">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button id="btnGroupDrop2" type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop2" style="">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button id="btnGroupDrop3" type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop3" style="">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button id="btnGroupDrop4" type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop4" style="">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This corresponds to four different styling options for `selectInput`. If I want to apply the success styling of the above code to a `selectInput`, where do I put it: As options to the relevant `selectInput`? In some header or tags for Shiny? Somewhere else?

I have already put the:

```
tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "mytheme.css"))
```

In my R-script, but I don't know what to do next. Trying to read up on CSS now.

Edit: An example. My radio buttons right now look like:

[image]

I want them to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid, just use buttons from here:

https://shinyapps.dreamrs.fr/shinyWidgets/